# How do I include a different file if my user is logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m using Rails 4.2.5.  I have this line in my “app/views/layouts/application.html.erb” file …

```
<%= yield %>
```

If the user is logged in, I would like to display the content from the page “./app/views/user_objects/index.html.erb” but if they are not, I would like to display content from the page “app/views/pages/_welcome.html.erb”.  I don’t know how to set this up.  In my config/routes.rb file I have

```
constraints lambda { |req| !req.session[:user_id].blank? } do
  root :to => 'user_objects#index', as: "dashboard"
end

root to: 'pages#index'
```

but that is displaying the “./app/views/user_objects/index.html.erb” file at all times, even if the user is not logged in.  What do I need to add (or remove) to allow me to display the normal welcome page content if the user is not logged in?

Comment: Are you using Devise for login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this a bit different. In my **config/routes.rb** I'd have just the usual

```
root 'pages#index'
```

and then I'd change my **index method** at **app/controllers/pages_controller.rb** to

```
def index
  if logged_user? 
    render 'user_objects/index'
  end
end
```

and then I'd put all this logic to say if the user is logged in a **logged_user? method** like

```
def logged_user?
  !session[:user_id].blank?
end
```

There are other ways to to this, of course. But always keep the [KISS Principle](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keep_It_Simple) in mind.

If you really want to understand all the rendering process, it would be better to give some attention to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html